# Selected on an option not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm loading the selected via a PHP shorthand if statement. Inspecting the options shows the correct item has the `selected` attribute but it's not actually selected. I've also used `selected="selected"` but it didn't work either. I even tried hardcoding the attribute and it still didn't work:

```
<select id="popUpType" name="popUpType" class="widefat">
    <option value="none" <?php echo ($popUpType == 'none') ? "selected" : ""; ?>>None</option>
    <option value="entry" <?php echo ($popUpType == 'entry') ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Entry</option>
    <option value="exit" <?php echo ($popUpType == 'exit') ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Exit</option>
    <option value="event-based" <?php echo ($popUpType == 'event-based') ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Event-Based</option>
    <option value="timed" <?php echo ($popUpType == 'timed') ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Timed</option>
</select>
```

I'm building this in WordPress and testing in the latest version of Chrome. I've done this before and never had an issue.

This is the output after a selection is made and submitted:

```
<select id="popUpType" name="popUpType" class="widefat">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="entry" selected>Entry</option>
    <option value="exit">Exit</option>
    <option value="event-based">Event-Based</option>
    <option value="timed">Timed</option>
</select>
```

Comment: look at your html source, see what that read as. Echo out `$popUpType`, check for errors also. Not much I can offer here.

Comment: I've edited my question with the output. No matter what the select box always shows the first one no matter what.

Comment: If I change the `id` it works fine... seriously. Nothing else on the page has the same id.

Comment: Try disabling javascript and see if the problem remains. Might be a conflicting javascript code

Answer (score 0):

I run your html and it gives right output. Please check css and javascript    inherited. Please see the link -

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/4yoy3L0v/][1]
```